# How to get text without child nodes in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML

```
<title>Products</title>
<products xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="products.xsd">
  <product>
    The product called <name>Lorem</name> is available for <price>€ 80</price> only.
  </product>
</products>
```

Now I want to format the XML above. The `name` should have, for instance, a red color and the `price` should be blue.

I have tried the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="products/product">
      <div>
        <p style="font-weight:bold">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
          <span style="color:red"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></span>
          <span style="color:blue"><xsl:value-of select="price"/></span>
        </p>
      </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But this doesn't work at all...

Also I want to format the title but I am not sure how to get the content in the XSLT file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try a different approach, along the lines of:

```
<xsl:template match="product">
    <div>
        <p style="font-weight:bold">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name">
    <span style="color:red">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="price">
    <span style="color:blue">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this is incomplete - but so is the the code you have provided.

> Also I want to format the title

In the same manner, add a template matching `title`.